# How to map two action names with one action tag in Struts 2

Tags: model-view-controller, configuration, struts2, action-mapping

I have a method `ajouterModifierClient()` in my action class `pl.admin.HomeAction` that handles both operations, the add operation and the update operation.

How to map two disctinct action names in on single action tag.

**Here is my wanted result:**

```xml
<action name="{ajouter,modifier}-client" class="pl.admin.HomeAction" method="ajouterModifierClient">
    <result name="success">ajouterModifierClient.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but what's the point of trying to wedge this into a single `<action>` element? Totally doable (see answer), but harder to read, more confusing to modify, and harder to search for. I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matcher regex:

```xml
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />

<action name="{(ajouter|modifier)}-client" class="pl.admin.HomeAction" method="ajouterModifierClient">
    <result name="success">ajouterModifierClient.jsp</result>
</action>
```